# created linux image in azure, cant seem to deploy

Tags: azure

created an image from a linuxvm and all went well until i tried to deploy. got the following error:

Deployment failed. Correlation ID: 52a94279-233b-45c1-96c4-8c9f3d5d95bc. {
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidParameter",
    "message": "StorageProfile.dataDisks.lun does not have required value(s) for image specified in storage profile.",
    "target": "storageProfile"
  }
}

any ideas?

Comment: Please add more details about your deployment configuration, as the error is clearly stating that there are invalid parameters

Answer (score 0):

When you create the Linux and add the data disk to the VM in the template, the disk object `lun` is necessary and you must input an integer parameter.

> Specifies the logical unit number of the data disk. This value is used
>   to identify data disks within the VM and therefore must be unique for
>   each data disk attached to a VM

For more details, see [Datadisk object in the template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.compute/2018-10-01/virtualmachines#datadisk-object).